# Unable to understand the subtraction result

Tags: ruby, aptana

I executed the following line in Ruby (Aptana IDE)

```
puts 3.3 - 2.7 == 0.6    #which should be true
```

and I got the result as

```
false
```

Then I executed

```
puts 3.3 - 2.7
```

and got the result as

```
0.5999999999999996
```

Can anybody please explain about whats going on? Why I got 0.5999999999999996 instead of 0.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

The right way to handle this in Ruby is to use the `BigDecimal` class

```
> require 'bigdecimal'
true

> a = BigDecimal.new('3.3')
3.3

> b = BigDecimal.new('2.7')
2.7

> c = BigDecimal.new('0.6')
0.6

> a - b == c
true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's floating point math. Computers can't represent some values exactly. You can use Ruby's String format to get a string version:

```
'%0.1f' % (3.3 - 2.7) # => "0.6"
```

Or adjust your math to multiply your values by the precision you want, then remove that offset:

```
(3.3 * 10 - 2.7 * 10) / 10 # => 0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you should ask yourself (or yourinterpreter) is

*how is 0.6 different from 0.5999999999999996 in my machine?*

and the answer is that it is not different. Floating point number 0.5999999999999996 **is** 0.6 in your machine because the precision your interpreter is using for floating point numbers can not distinguish the two.

If this representation causes problems you can use explicit rounding [Float#round](http://apidock.com/ruby/Float/round)

```
(3.3 - 2.7).round(1)
#=> 0.6
```

or special formatting (check [Kernel#sprintf](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf) for more opts)

```
"%0.1f" % (3.3 - 2.7)
#=> "0.6"
```